# Creating a deployment package in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, deployment, windows-installer

With VS 2010, we used the setup and deployment project to create and ship the MSIs to another dept for installing.  With VS 2012, what would be a good strategy to send deployment packages?

Some have recommended using publishing profiles along with web deploy packages. But with all the options out there, I'm wondering which method is the recommended one today.

Comment: Take the time to learn [WIX](http://wix.codeplex.com/), it has a learning curve but is extremely flexable

Comment: What kind of application are you deploying?